# $\| f' g\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)} + \|fg'\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}\le C\left( \|f g\|_{L^2} +\|f'g'\|_{L^2} + \|f'' g \|_{L^2} + \| f g''\|_{L^2}\right)$ holds?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, functional-inequalities

I want to know that the following inequality holds
$$
\| f' g\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)} + \|fg'\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}\le ^\exists C_{>0} \left( \|f g\|_{L^2} +\|f'g'\|_{L^2} + \|f'' g \|_{L^2} + \| f g''\|_{L^2}\right).
$$
Here $'$ means derivatives.

Comment: What is $f$ and $g$ ?

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are real-valued functions of $x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f' g$ and $g\, f'$ are compact supported, the inequality holds as a consequence of the [Wirtinger's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions) and the [Minkowski's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

I would not bet that your inequality holds without further assumptions on the decay of $f' g$ and $g\,f'$. The classical [Poincaré's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality) also requires that $\Omega$ is a bounded regular domain.

To provide a counter-example, I would try something like:
$$(f g')(x)=\frac{\sin\sqrt{|x|}}{\log(2+|x|) \sqrt{1+|x|}},\qquad (f' g)(x)=\frac{\cos\sqrt{|x|}}{\log(2+|x|) \sqrt{1+|x|}},$$
in order to have functions that behave like trigonometrical polynomials with a slowly increasing period. This should make the constant in the Wirtinger's inequality arbitrarily large.